# Issues with doing a P2V on Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, vmware-esx

I shutdown all Exchange services on the physical box and did a convert. Everything converted fine. Server booted up no issues and I could receive email from the outside world with no issues. But I am unable to send emails internally or externally. They just sit in the Outbox.

I also disabled the DHCPClient service as I didn't want the server to get an IP address from DHCP when it first came online. It came online with no IP, then I used console to assign the correct static IP address (same one on the physical server) and rebooted.

I ran the Exchange Troubleshooting Agent and it gave me the following errors:

The value for the '\MSExchangeIS Mailbox\Messages Queued For Submission' counter on server exchange is greater than zero (average value is 8.8) and it appears that 'MSExchangeMailSubmission' is failing to submit messages to at least one computer with the Hub Transport server role installed over the last minute.

Found 1 computers with the Hub Transport server role installed in the same Active Directory site as server exchange using local Active Directory site GUID 'ce8a4367-1bf6-4825-9cac-c4e2b115c450'.

Check Local Active Directory Site Hub Transport Server Role Health (Mailflow_CheckLocalBhHealth1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1)

I have one Exchange server with all the roles on it.

Has anyone see this before when doing a convert? Please help :(

Comment: Have you checked the IP addresses that your send and receive connectors are listening on?

Comment: Did you remove the original NICs from the system? Directions: http://forums.ngemu.com/hardware-discussion/113370-remove-non-present-devices-system.html

Answer (score 6):

Turn the DHCP Client service back on. It is used to register DNS records as well as [DNS lookups](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268674).

With that service off, you shouldn't be able to resolve any DNS names from that server, which would explain why no mail could be sent from it.

Comment: +1. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264539/EN-US/

Comment: Can I +5 this? :-)

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying tons of difference fixes online I was finally able to resolve my exchange 2010 issue after migrating to vmware esxi 5. E-mails would go to drafts and I could also not delete them. E-mails were coming in fine but could not send. After several reboots and "fixes" I finally restarted the service "Microsoft Exchange Mail Submission" and all e-mail in queue started sending. Everything is working ok now and didn't even have to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Stop all exchange services on the vm.  Rename your log directories, ex mine were first and second storage group, i renamed them to ORIGFirst Storage group and ORIGSecond storage group.  I then re-created the Folders First and Second Storage group with nothing in them.  Restarted all exchange services and mail started flowing.